# gRPC cocoapod, 'memory' file not found

Tags: c++, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Recently I added FirebaseFirestore dependency to my Podfile and after that compiler began to produce an error `'memory' file not found` in `grpc_audit_logging.h` module.
I have no idea how to fix it, I googled a lot but didn't find any similar issue. It's just a standard c++ library isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was referenced recently here:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/34921

Perhaps updating your dependencies will resolve the issue? The problem definitely is "It's just a standard c++ library"; my guess is that you are not linking in the c++ stdlib into your project. However, I'm not sure what that entails for your environment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).